Custom taxonomy still using query URL after fixing error
I made a mistake when creating a new custom taxonomy and custom post type. Here's the line in the custom taxonomy with the error...
register_taxonomy('resource-category', ['qp_resource'], $args);
The post type should be qp_resources and not qp_resource.
This error resulted in /resource-category/white-paper/ becoming /resources/?_sft_resource-category=white-paper.
After I noticed the error, I fixed it and flushed permalinks, it's still converting to the query style URL. Just to check that it was not another issue, I created a new custom taxonomy resource-type. It works fine with no issues. I also tried deleting resource-category, uploading the plugin, flushing permalinks, re-adding resource-category, reuploading and reflushing again with no luck.
I prefer to use  resource-category. Does anybody know what I can do to keep that and not have the URLs changed to queries?

To address the issue of your custom taxonomy resource-category not displaying correctly even after fixing the custom post type and flushing permalinks, you can follow these steps:

Double-check the Registration Code.
Flush Permalinks Again: Go to Settings > Permalinks and click on Save Changes. This will flush the rewrite rules and update the permalinks.
Clear Caches: Ensure that any caching plugins or server-side caching are cleared. Sometimes, changes are not immediately reflected due to cached data.
Check for Conflicts: Deactivate all other plugins and switch to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty-One) to check if there is any conflict causing the issue. If the problem is resolved, reactivate your plugins one by one and switch back to your theme to identify the conflict.

